# Getting error while saving byte array in HashMap

Tags: android, arrays, hashmap, retrofit, android-glide

In my app I'm doing request with Retrofit for getting byte array.Then I need to save this byte[] in HashMap and after that load with Glide. Ok, here's my code.

```
public class SimpleClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Activity activity = SimpleClass.this;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private HashMap<String, byte[]> imageHashMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getImageBytes("Image1");
    }

    public void getImageBytes(final String imageName) {
        Call<ResponseBody> getChatImage = retrofitClient.getImagesBytes(imageName);
        getChatImage.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        imageHashMap.put("Key1", response.body().bytes());
                        Glide.with(activity).load(response.body().bytes()).fitCenter().into(imageView);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error cought in catch block:  " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Response is not successful: " + response.errorBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So when I want to put the byte[] in HashMap, I'm getting error like this in catch block - `java.io.IOException: Content-Length (25139) and stream length (0) disagree`. So when I'm removing this line - `imageHashMap.put("Key1", response.body().bytes());`, all works fine. So why I can't put byte[] in HashMap? Yes and one more question too. What would be good to use: HashMap or LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 0):

A byte[] (or any array) can't work properly as a key in a HashMap, since arrays don't override equals, so two arrays will be considered equal only if they refer to the same object.

You'll have to wrap your byte[] in some custom class that overrides hashCode and equals, and use that custom class as the key to your HashMap.

Comment: Bro, I'm using byte[] as a value. My key is a string.